# react native - Notify parent component of state update in child component with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

I am currently trying to update react native hook state inside my parent functional component based on changes made in my child class component. I've been looking at and trying various solutions, but I haven't found one that's about functional and class components. Below is my code, what it's supposed to do, what errors I'm getting, and what I've tried.

**What it's supposed to do**

1. There's a button on the Overview Cards that takes you to Add Card.
2. AddCard allows you to fill out some TextInput boxes
3. AddCard should allow you to press the save button and be taken back to the Overview Card screen.
4. The information the user filled out during Step 2, should be displayed on the Overview Card screen.

I am getting stuck at Step 4.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, ShadowPropTypesIOS } from 'react-native';
import AddCard from './components/AddCard.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

// function returnData(id, firstTwo, lastFour, recentAmount) {
//   this.setState({id: id, firstTwoDigits: firstTwo, lastFourDigits: lastFour, currentAmt: recentAmount});
// }

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [id, setID ] = useState(0);
  // const [firstTwo, setFirstTwoDigits] = useState(0);
  const [lastFour, setLastFourDigits] = useState(0);
  const [recentAmount, setRecentAmount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
      <Button title="Add Card" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add Card')}/>
      <Text>
      CardID: {id}
      </Text>
      <Text>
      Last Four Digits: {lastFour}
      </Text>
      <Text>
      Current Amount: {recentAmount}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle} >VISA xxxx</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>MASTERCARD xxxx</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>AMEX xxxx</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function AddCardScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.addCardContainer}>
      <AddCard 
      navigation={navigation}
      id={id}
      // firstTwo={firstTwo}
      // lastFour={lastFour}
      // recentAmount={recentAmount} 
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'Overview Cards' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add Card" component={AddCardScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
// function AddCardButton(){
//       return (
//           <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
//               <TouchableOpacity>
//                   <Text style={styles.button}>Add Card</Text>
//               </TouchableOpacity>
//           </View>
//       );
//   }

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  homeContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ef95b1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  addCardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#28cdf0',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  button: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    marginTop: 15,
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#2565ae',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 12,
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: 10,
    textAlign:'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    padding: 10,
  }
});
```

AddCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
// import { loadSettings, saveSettings } from '../storage/settingsStorage';

class AddCardScreen extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        firstTwo  : '',
        lastFour  : '',
        recentAmt : ''
    };

    this.addFT = this.addFT.bind(this)
    this.addLF = this.addLF.bind(this)
    this.addRecAmt = this.addRecAmt.bind(this)
   }

   static navigationOptions = {
       title: 'Add Card'
    };

   addFT(firstTwo) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state.firstTwo, { firstTwo }));
  }

  addLF(lastFour) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state.lastFour, { lastFour }));
  }

  addRecAmt(recentAmt) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state.recentAmt, { recentAmt }));
  }

   handleSubmit() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    alert('New card saved. Returning to Home to view addition.');
    // navigation.state.params.returnData('123', this.firstTwo, this.lastFour, this.recentAmt);
    navigation.navigate('Home', this.firstTwo, this.lastFour, this.recentAmt);
  }

    render() {
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput 
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder="First two digits of card"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                    keyboardType={'number-pad'}
                    maxLength = {2}

                    // onChangeText={this.addFT}
                    // inputValFT={this.state.firstTwo}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder="Last four digits of card"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                    keyboardType={'number-pad'}
                    maxLength = {4}

                    // onChangeText={this.addLF}
                    // inputValLF={this.state.lastFour}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder="Most recent dollar amount"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                    keyboardType={'decimal-pad'}

                    // onChangeText={this.addRecAmt}
                    // inputValRA={this.state.recentAmt}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={styles.saveButton}
                    onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}>Save</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
// () => navigation.navigate('Home') line 81
export default AddCardScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputContainer: {
        paddingTop: 15
      },
      textInput: {
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 17,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20
      },
      saveButton: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007BFF',
        backgroundColor: '#007BFF',
        padding: 15,
        margin: 5
      },
      saveButtonText: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
      }

});
```

**What I've tried:**

1. I've tried adding a React Hook to my parent component, HomeScreen. I added `const [id, setID] = useState(0);` and so on. Then I called the objects in the three `<Text>` that are inside the `return()`. I tried to add id={id} and so on (you can see the rest is commented out. At first, those parts weren't commented out, but I was getting the error: `Can't find variable: firstTwo`. The app won't load at all when this error exists.
2. I noticed that I wasn't using the `addFT, addLF, and addRecAmt` functions in AddCard.js at all (since I commented the parts where they're called since it wasn't working), which I felt might be an issue too. I added them to `handleSubmit()`.

Like this:

```
handleSubmit(firstTwo, lastFour, recentAmt) {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.addFT(firstTwo);
    this.addLF(lastFour);
    this.addRecAmt(recentAmt);
    alert('New card saved. Returning to Home to view addition.');
    // navigation.state.params.returnData('123', this.firstTwo, this.lastFour, this.recentAmt);
    navigation.navigate('Home', this.firstTwo, this.lastFour, this.recentAmt);
  }
```

I had to comment id={id} out because if I didn't that would produce the same error as firstTwo would when uncommented. The app loads fine with this change to App.js and AddCard.js. I think this may be on the right track of where I want to do, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you were right in general, in `handleSubmit` you should navigate to your `Home` screen with params (other steps data)

```
handleSubmit(firstTwo, lastFour, recentAmt) {
  ...
  navigation.navigate('Home', {
    firstTwo: this.state.firstTwo,
    lastFour: this.state.lastFour,
    recentAmt: this.state.recentAmt,
  });
}
```

Now it `Home` screen the prop `route` with params should be available:

```
function HomeScreen({ route }) {
  const { firstTwo, lastFour, recentAmt } = route.params || {}; // in case we have no params it is undefined by the default

  const [lastFour, setLastFourDigits] = useState(lastFour || ''); // using it as a default value for our state variable
  ...
}
```

let me know it it helped or not ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much, I think I'm closer to fixing this! I implemented your suggestions and it doesn't break when I load the app up. It isn't updating the state on the Overview Cards page yet though.

Here's two codepile links to the updated code:
(App.js) https://www.codepile.net/pile/dQBObd2Z
(AddCard.js) https://www.codepile.net/pile/EMVK9WxY

Comment: @NoIDEUh I've updated my original answer - in other words, you should take & pass state entries, so for ex it will be `firstTwo: this.state.firstTwo,` instead of just `firstTwo: this.firstTwo,`

let me know if it fixes your issue, I've run your files on mine and it works fine